# Auto compelete success shows wrong data

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I  have a jQuery code for sending keywords to another page. On that page I have name of all of airports all over the world as string and I filter those cities with a keyword on URL. My code works good for instance when I type istanbul in my textbox it return Airports of Istanbul that contains this word on that string.

When I type the word quickly it sends the complete word and I checked it on network tab and I expect to returns only "Istanbul" but in some cases it returns all of the words with "stan" on them. when i clear the textbox and type the word slower than before it returns the correct cities. Is this issue because of the loading time Process ?

how can I resolve this problem ?

here is my code :

```js
$('.country').each(function() {
$(this).on('keyup', function(e) {
   var _this = this;

   var element = $(this).val().length;
    if (e.which !== 0 &&
        !e.ctrlKey && !e.metaKey && !e.altKey
    ) {
        if (element > 2) {
            var val = $(this).val()
            val = val.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + val.substr(1).toLowerCase();
            $(this).val(val)
            $.ajax({
                url: "secondpage.html",
                type: "get",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: {
                    key: $(this).val()
                },
                success: function(result) {

                    $(_this).closest(".search_div").find(".result").empty().html(result)
                }
            })
   
        }
    }
})
})
```

```html
<div class="search_div"> 
<input type="text" value=""  class="country" autocomplete="off" />
<div class="result"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are typing fast it may happen that response from previous ajax request has just arrived but you have already typed in the next character so the old response isn't required anymore .It's like you type in 'g' the request is sent for which the server send{'germany','georgia'} but before this response could arrive you type 'h' so again we request for'gh' gets sent meanwhile the old response arrives and replaces html with Germany/Georgia which is wrong , to prevent this you need to cancel the old ajax request's effect ie. response will arrive but jQuery will ignore it.

```
var prevXHR = null; //global

$('.country').each(function() {

  $(this).on('keyup', function(e) {
    //.. code

    //...code 

    prevXHR = $.ajax({
                 url: "secondpage.html",
                 type: "get",
                 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                 data: {
                     key: $(this).val()
                 },
                 success: function(result) {
                    //..code
                 },
                 beforeSend: function(){
                     if(prevXHR && prevXHR.readyState != 4){
                         //before sending any new request neutralize any pending ajax call
                         prevXHR.abort();
                         prevXHR = null;
                     }
                 }

              });
  });
});
```

Also as Stavm has suggested you should add some delay like 500ms so inputs will be sent only in those slots e.g. if user enters 'a' at 0.2 sec and then 'm' at 0.3 but then changes mind hits backspace and types 'z'  at 0.4 so at 0.5 'az' is sent.No one is that much fast but you get the idea.

Comment: when dealing with ajax on each `keyup` event, I suggest adding a slight delay between requests. `delay: 500` to the `$.ajax()` call is somehow a standard. also `minLength: 1` would prevent suggestions when the input is empty.

Comment: @Viney Thanks a lot can you explain this part ? if(prevXHR && prevXHR.readyState != 4)?  what is 4 ?

Comment: @aynaz it means cancel previous ajax only if it's stil pending because there is no point cancelling a completed request  coz a completed request must have already shown its effect and trying to cancel a completed ajax call may throw a warning https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState

Comment: We are just checking if any previous ajax exists and if so is it cancellable

Comment: @Viney why you wrote 4 ?

Comment: 4 is the code for completion (`DONE`) if readyState property of ajax (more specifically XHR) object is 4 means ajax request has been responded completely.At first when request is sent (and response is yet to come) it's 1  on response headers arrival it changes to 2 then browser is reading response stream (continuing) is 3 then finally 4 on complete response availability.See this for more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState